# CSS3 Height animation shim/polyfill

Tags: javascript, html, css, polyfills, shim

So I was wondering if anyone knew of a good javascript shim to enhance the animations (particularly height) using javascript in IE8?  Or am I going to have to write one myself?  :/

Thanks!

Comment: The Jquery animations are awful.  Not smooth at all.

Comment: I guess you should write one yourself then - good luck with making plain javascript perfectly smooth in all circumstances.  It would be best to use CSS3 animations when supported and fallback to javascript animations when required.  I've written a slideshow that has three paths based on capabilities (CSS3, IE filter effects, plain javascript).

Comment: I am doing that now, but I have seen places where people have created smooth animations in IE. For example, look at the Gmail interface in IE8. The panel on the left still shinks and grows and it is smooth.  Obv, CSS3 in new browsers, but still works in IE somehow.

Comment: IE has filter animations that are implemented in native code.

Comment: Can you use one of those to manipulate the height?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ahh, have never seen these before.  They are a nightmare to implement though.  Am going to look through and see what I can manage.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would create a filter to toggle one div up, and then another down?  I am looking at the docs, but it's so confusing.  Do I create 2 CSS classes with the filters and toggle them?  I see that you have to call '.play()' to get them to run.

Comment: I've done it before, but almost two years ago.  It has sliding transitions for that type of effect.  I'd suggest you Google for examples and study the doc on the MS site.  It's all there as I figured it out myself once, but I don't remember the details now.